# How can I convert for loop to list functions in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm reading The Big Nerd Ranch Guide and here is a question that wants you to use the list functions instead of for loop

```
var count = 0
    for (answer in answerList) {
        if (!answer.isCorrect) {
            answer.isEnabled = false
            answer.isSelected = false // deselect when answer is disabled
            count++
            if (count == 2) {
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

here is my solution, but I don't know how to deal with count

```
var count = 0
    answerList
            .filter { !it.isCorrect }
            .forEach {
                it.isSelected  = false
                it.isSelected = false
                count++
            }
            .takeIf { count == 2 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform the actions for the first two (at most) items that are "not correct", you could do this, with [`take`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take.html):

```
answerList
        .filter { !it.isCorrect }
        .take(2)
        .forEach {
            it.isEnabled = false
            it.isSelected = false
        }
```

Comment: A good example of how the functional style can be not just more concise, but also more readable (as it describes _what_ to do, not _how_ to do it).